# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/chat from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, localhost

I am facing issues in proxying request from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000. I have tried numerous amount of ways in typing the proxy as http://localhost:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but the same error is being repeated.[image]

This is the above screenshot where Uncaught (in promise) error is occurring.
Please help me in resolving this issue as to what should be done in getting the proper response while proxying. I just want to see the data in the console but Uncaught error is appearing due to failure in proxy request.

Thanks
Ankan

I want to see the output of a data in the console. But instead, I am seeing Uncaught error which is appearing due to proxy failure.

Comment: Can you post the GET `/api/chat` endpoint code?

Comment: This is the endpoint code for Get /api/chat: 

app.get("/api/chat", (req, res) => {
  res.send(chats);
});

This is where the /api/chat is being used in the ChatPage component:

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ChatPage = () => {
  const fetchChats = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get("/api/chat");
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchChats();
  }, []);

  return <div>Chat Page</div>;
};

export default ChatPage;